# Disable Hyerperlink in a Div using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have div with Textbox, label and hyperlink it it. I want to disable /enable the elements in it. I am using this code.

$('#Content_2 :input').attr('disabled', true);

## Content_2 - is a div

But this leaves the hyerperlink and label enabled. How can modify this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#Content_2 :input').attr('disabled', true);

only disables all <input /> element inside #Content_2 not <a>
```

try

```
$('#Content_2 :input,#Content_2 a,#Content_2 span').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

to enable them use:

```
$('#Content_2 :input,#Content_2 a,#Content_2 span').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: `:input` doesn't select `<input>` elements only, that would be the `input` (no colon) element selector :)

Answer (score 3):

[`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/) is only for input type (`<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>` and `<button>`) elements, for the others you'll need to add to the selector:

```
$('#Content_2').find(':input, label').attr('disabled', true);
```

You can also do one selector, I just find this a bit cleaner to look at, the single selector would be:

```
$('#Content_2 :input, #Content_2 label').attr('disabled', true);
```

---

*Base on comments:*  Now for the anchors, that one's a little different, you're better off binding the events unobtrusively, for example:

```
$('#Content_2').delegate('img.toggle:not(.disabled)', 'click', function(e) {
  window.scroll(150,650);
  tooglecargoLoading();
});
```

Then that link can just be the `<img>` itself, like this:

```
<img class="toggle" src="images/accept_but1.jpg" width="119" height="20" border="0" />
```

To enable/disable it, just add/remove the `disabled` class, like this:

```
$("#Content_2 img.toggle").addClass("disabled");
//to re-enable:
$("#Content_2 img.toggle").removeClass("disabled");
```

By doing this, the link will/won't match the selector when the `click` event bubbles...meaning it'll be effectively disabled.  There are also *other* ways to do this, like putting the

Comment: $('#Content_2').find(':input, label, a').attr('disabled', true);
 and it diables everying the but this tag is not disabled.                      <a href="javascript:scroll(150,650)" onclick="tooglecargoLoading();" ><img src="images/accept_but1.jpg" width="119" height="20" border="0" /></a>

Comment: @Techonthenet - do you want to permanently disable it, or you plan to re-enable it later?

Comment: I plan to re-enable it later. Like toggling

Comment: @Techonthenet - mm  that's a bit tricky, since you're using in-line handlers, no chance of binding those things unobtrusively? e.g. no inline `javascript:` or `onclick`?

Comment: I use the Javascript method to focus the control to a particular location. Will it create problem ?

Comment: @Techonthenet - try the updated answer, it's designed to make this easier...there are *other* methods as well, but without knowing your markup I can't say for *sure* which way you should go (though many ways work).